# How to place result grid at top right, i.e the place at which sql addition is in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to mysql workbench. That result grid is put at the middle by default is annoying for me. So I want to put it at the top right. It seems that there is no such setting.
Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know It's not possible in workbench. However, You can use a different IDE if you want. You can use the `Data Grip by Jet Brains`. I have not used `Data Grip` personally but I have used their other product `PyCharme` and it's phenomenal. I believe it will fulfill your requirement. You can download `Data Grip` from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/). Unfortunately, there is no community edition available yet. So you will get 30 days of a free trial. Apart from this, if you want to explore other alternatives then visit [this](https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/?platform=windows).